# Can flexible baseboards come in lengths longer than 8'

Tags: trim

My contractor is telling me that it is not possible to get flexible baseboard moldings longer than 8'. But my curved section is 12'. I currently have to use 2 flexible moldings which I believe looks bad. How can I get a longer molding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PVC baseboard moldings are readily available in 12' (and probably longer). For example, http://www.lowes.com/pd_310628-1487-07527_0__?productId=3340764 (EverTrue 3.25-in x 12-ft Interior/Exterior PVC Baseboard). Your contractor needs to look a little harder.